# Manejo de JSON Java

Tags: java, json

Buen Dia, 
Tengo que consumir un json de un lading que se encuentra almacenado en mysql, ya obtengo el campo pero al tratar de leer el json me genera error, el json que consumo es el siguiente:

```
[{
    "label": "Nombre Completo",
    "value": "oscar",
    "identifier": "field20",
    "type": "oneLineText",
    "page": 1,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "Nu00famero de identificaciu00f3n",
    "value": "7747777",
    "identifier": "field21",
    "type": "oneLineText",
    "page": 1,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "Correo electru00f3nico",
    "value": "oscarrv@medplus.com.co",
    "identifier": "field46",
    "type": "email",
    "page": 1,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "Celular",
    "value": "555545454",
    "identifier": "field23",
    "type": "oneLineText",
    "page": 1,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "Ciudad",
    "value": "Bogota",
    "identifier": "field24",
    "type": "dropdown",
    "page": 1,
    "page_name": "",
    "options": [{
        "value": "",
        "show": "Ciudad"
    }, {
        "value": "Bogota",
        "show": "Bogota"
    }],
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "QUIERO CONOCER Mu00c1S",
    "value": "QUIERO CONOCER M&Aacute;S",
    "identifier": "field25",
    "type": "heading",
    "page": 1,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "",
    "value": "",
    "identifier": "field26",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "page": 1,
    "page_name": "",
    "options": [{
        "value": "Acepto la polu00edtica de privacidad",
        "show": "Acepto la polu00edtica de privacidad"
    }],
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "u00bfTienes medicina prepagada?",
    "value": "&iquest;Tienes medicina prepagada?",
    "identifier": "field28",
    "type": "heading",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "fix",
    "value": "",
    "identifier": "field44",
    "type": "heading",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "25%"
}, {
    "label": "",
    "value": "1",
    "identifier": "field27",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "options": [{
        "value": "1",
        "show": "Su00ed"
    }, {
        "value": "2",
        "show": "No"
    }],
    "width": "50%"
}, {
    "label": "fix",
    "value": "",
    "identifier": "field45",
    "type": "heading",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "25%"
}, {
    "label": "u00bfCuu00e1l?",
    "value": "&iquest;Cu&aacute;l?",
    "identifier": "field29",
    "type": "heading",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "",
    "value": "Colmedica",
    "identifier": "field19",
    "type": "oneLineText",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "u00bfQuu00e9 aspecto mejoraru00edas en tu plan actual de salud?",
    "value": "&iquest;Qu&eacute; aspecto mejorar&iacute;as en tu plan actual de salud?",
    "identifier": "field30",
    "type": "heading",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "Aspectos",
    "value": "Red M&eacute;dica",
    "identifier": "field31",
    "type": "dropdown",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "options": [{
        "value": "",
        "show": "Cobertura"
    }, {
        "value": "Red Mu00e9dica",
        "show": "Red Mu00e9dica"
    }, {
        "value": "Beneficios Adicionales",
        "show": "Beneficios Adicionales"
    }, {
        "value": "Precio",
        "show": "Precio"
    }],
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "u00bfQuu00e9 aspecto es mu00e1s relevante al elegir tu plan de salud?",
    "value": "&iquest;Qu&eacute; aspecto es m&aacute;s relevante al elegir tu plan de salud?",
    "identifier": "field34",
    "type": "heading",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "width": "100%"
}, {
    "label": "relevante",
    "value": "",
    "identifier": "field35",
    "type": "dropdown",
    "page": 2,
    "page_name": "",
    "options": [{
        "value": "",
        "show": "Red amplia de mu00e9dicos"
    }, {
        "value": "Variedad de especialidades mu00e9dicas",
        "show": "Variedad de especialidades mu00e9dicas"
    }, {
        "value": "Beneficios adicionales",
        "show": "Beneficios adicionales"
    }, {
        "value": "Precio del plan",
        "show": "Precio del plan"
    }],
    "width": "100%"
}]
```

Lo almaceno en un JSONArray y lo almacena sin problemas, el error esta al tratarlo de volver un JSONObject, lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
public void mensaje() throws SQLException, JSONException{

    List<JSONArray> jsons = conexionDBDao.getNewOpportunities();

    for(int i=0;i<jsons.size();i++){

        for(int x=0;x<jsons.get(i).length();x++){

           JSONObject obj = jsons.get(i).getJSONObject(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Me genera el siguiente Error

```
org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:258) ~[jettison-1.2.jar:1.2]
at com.medplus.genoma.scheduler.Scheduler.mensaje(Scheduler.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

***Actualizando:***

El metodo getNewOpportunities es el siguiente

```
public List<JSONArray> getNewOpportunities () throws SQLException{

     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX/db","user", "pass");


     Statement s = conn.createStatement(); 
     ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("SELECT content FROM db.table;");

     List<JSONArray> json = new ArrayList<>();

     while(rs.next()){

         JSONArray j = new JSONArray();

         j.put(rs.getString("content").replace("\\",""));   

         json.add(j);
     }

     conn.close();

     return json;

 }
```

Gracias

Comment: Cual es la línea 32 de Scheduler.java?

Comment: Parece que la estructura del JSON no es la que esperabas... prueba a imprimir en consola ese *supuesto* objeto: `jsons.get(i).get(x).toString();`

Comment: La linea 32 es la que hace referencia a  JSONObject obj = jsons.get(i).getJSONObject(x);

Comment: al imprimir es donde me genera ese error, si imprimo solo el JSONArray si me imprime el json bien pero en array, necesito es poder acceder a esos valores

Comment: ¿Es posible conocer la manera en que creas la lista en `conexionDBDao.getNewOpportunities();`?

Comment: Ya adjunte el método donde extraigo el JSON

Comment: Por que realizas el `replace("\\",""))`, intenta sin hacerle replace, algunas veces esos caracteres son saltos de lineas, ya que el json se guarda con formato. imaginate esto `\n` luego del replace queda la `n`, en ese momento el formato json se rompe.

Comment: fijate en este asunto es casi lo mismo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/202375/pasar-un-jsonarray-a-un-arrylist/202392#202392

Comment: Se me olvido agregar que las [cadenas en json](https://www.json.org/) van entre comillas dobles, y las cadenas en java tambien van entre comillas dobles, por tal razon se coloca el escape `\"` y para los saltos de lineas `\n` solo cuando se guarda con identacion para este ultimo. @EmilioGarcia coloca un muy buen ejemplo.

Comment: Genera el mismo error al quitar ese remplazo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos.

Como indica el error:

> org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.

El dato que estás insertando en tu `JSONArray` no es explícitamente un `JSONObject` y lo puedes ver en la documentación de la librería: [Documentación jettison](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONArray.html).

El método que estás utilizando es `put(Object value);`.

Si observamos tu código en esta línea: `j.put(rs.getString("content").replace("\\",""));`
nos daremos cuenta que estás pasando un `String` y no un `JSONObject`, por lo que sería lógico que al tratar de llamar `jsons.get(i).getJSONObject(x);` nos lance dicho error y de hecho la forma correcta es: `jsons.get(i).getString(x);`

Sin embargo, como indicaste, tú necesitas un `JSONObject` por lo que deberías hacer algo así:

```
String val = rs.getString("content").replace("\\",""); // Se obtiene la cadena de texto con el json
j.put(new JSONObject(val)); // Se construye el JSONObject a partir del String anterior
```

---

PD: Se asume que los valores de cada fila en tu base de datos tienen el formato de un `JSONObject` (inician y terminan con `{ ... }` y no de un `JSONArray` (inician y terminan con `[ ... ]`

---

**UPDATE**

Como los datos son leídos como `JSONArray` entonces podrías hacer algo así:

```
JSONArray j = new JSONArray(rs.getString("content").replace("\\",""));
json.add(j);
```

Comment: En mi base de datos es un JSONArray por que inicia y termina con `[...]`, estoy intentando de descomponer ese JSONArray en multiple JSONObjects, lo recibo como string por que es como mi base de datos me entrega pero al convertirlo es un JSONArray, en la linea de arriba muestro como me envia mi base de datos el json

Comment: Revisa el update

Comment: Gracias amigo, el put me estaba generando el error, pero con tu respuesta pude solucionar.